# How to make specific characters in edittext bold?

Tags: android

I have a EditText and a toggle button.

Scenario 1 :- I am typing normally in the EditText using softKeyboard.

Scenario 2 :- I press the toggle button. It's status changes to true. So, in this scenario, i want that when the toggle button is ON, my typeface of the Edittext should be Bold, But only for the string from that point on.

For Example :-
Scenario 1 : - I type "abcdef" in my EditText
Result : - abcdef

Scenario 2 : - Toggle Button Status is ON

Scenario 3 : - I type " ghijkl" in my EditText
Result : - abcde **ghijkl**

I Hope the scenario is clear now

Comment: please be clear what is requirement

Comment: i have edited my requirement with detailed scenario

Comment: @RahulGupta did you implement it? where did you put the current cursor position?

Comment: @kittu88 - The current position of the cursor that is. Wherever the current position is, i start from there only

Comment: @RahulGupta basically there are 2 static values in the answer below, s.length() >= 4 and android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 3, s.length() - 1. I have tried changing  if (s.length() >= editText1.getSelectionStart()+1) and android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), editText1.getSelectionStart(), s.length() - 1 but, this crashes the app when I try to clear the edittext. It will be very helpful if you give me the code snippet with the current cursor position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this in your Textwatcher add code like this..

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() >= 4) {
                s.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(
                        android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 3, s.length() - 1,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
```

you have check the condition and apply it to the text..here i am testing for only 4 chars.you have to change it based on your condition..

Comment: Where should I put the current cursor position?